# Purpose of JHipster Curator and JHipster Import Dashboards

Tags: java, monitoring, jhipster

The JHipster Console documentation generally explains the purpose of the suite, but not it's specific components. Can someone please clarify for me the purpose of the:

- JHipster Import Dashboards
- JHipster Curator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Elastic Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) is used to close and then delete Elasticsearch indices, it's run as a daily cron, it's important to maintain performance over time as open indexes consume lot of memory.

JHipster Import Dashboards is used for importing dashboards into Kibana, it's not intended to be run continuously.